# Literals in Mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule,

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/Strain/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /strain.php?id=$3&strain=$4&source=$2&area=$1 [L]
```

However, having the "Strain" in there doesn't seem to work. What would be the correct syntax for a hard-coded directory name?

Thanks :) Any help is much appreciated

EDIT: eg,`http://mysite.com/San-Diego/Store-Name/209-Blue-Dream`

Comment: is it 'Strain' or 'strain'? - also, an example of your test request would help - from you regex, it's something like 'string/Strain/string/string-string' ?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provide, there is no /Strain/ in the query, so it can't match. You may want to remove /Strain from the RewriteRule.

Comment: There's no way to do a rewrite with a hard-coded directory name?

Comment: Yes of course you can but ^([^/]*)/Strain/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ will match http://mysite.com/San-Diego/Strain/Store-Name/209-Blue-Dream not http://mysite.com/San-Diego/Store-Name/209-Blue-Dream